# Difference between if(prop in obj) and if(obj[prop])?

Tags: javascript

I'm working through TestDome.com and ran into this question.

> Implement the removeProperty function which takes an object and
>   property name, and does the following:
>
> If the object obj has a property prop, the function removes the
>   property from the object and returns true; in all other cases it
>   returns false.

My solution was this:

```
function removeProperty(obj, prop) {
  if (obj[prop]) {
    delete obj[prop];
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;    
  }
}
```

The test says that this doesn't work and their solution is:

```
function removeProperty(obj, prop) {
  if (prop in obj) {
    delete obj[prop];
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

For the life of me I can't figure out why my solution is wrong.

Edit: further examples.

```
const a = { b: 'c'};

if(a['b']) {console.log(true);} //true
if('b' in a) {console.log(true);} //true
```

Comment: `if ({a:0}['a']) ...` is false, `if('a' in {a:0})` is not.

Comment: `removeProperty({foo:0}, 'foo');` ought to return true, but it returns false with your code.

Comment: Same with `{foo:false}`, `{foo:undefined}`, etc.

Comment: `obj[prop]` points to the value in the object whereas `prop in obj` checks for the name of the property.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Comment: to be pedantic, it should be `if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))` to avoid prototype props... some will even insist on `if(hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)`, in case the object defines a hasOwnProperty own property.

Comment: if( obj[prop] ) is truthy right? Which is all I'm trying to accomplish. Why would "prop in obj" not be the same as "obj[prop]" in the sense of checking if it's truthy?

Comment: if the prop you're looking for will always be truthy, like an object or array, then the two are functionally interchangeable. It's when the prop can be falsy (like a number or string) where the behavior differes.

Comment: @dandavis That explains so much! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the following:

```js
obj = {
  prop: 1
};

// retrieves the property from the object
console.log(obj['prop']);    // 1

// checks if prop is in obj object
console.log('prop' in obj);     // true
```

In the case of an if statement, both will evaluate to true. However, if the value retrieved from `obj['prop']` is coerced to `false` the `if` block would not run. For example:

```js
obj = {
  prop: 0
};

// 0 convert to false so 
if (obj['prop']) {
  console.log('executed 1');
}

// prop is a property of obj so 
// 'prop' in obj will evaluate to true
if ('prop' in obj) {
  console.log('executed 2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have an object

```
const a = {apple: 0}
```

In this case, `a['apple']` would be falsy, where as `"apple" in a` would be truthy.

Therefore, if you want to delete some key, just delete the key directly. I believe you do not even need to check for it before deleting it.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the issue.